# Need logical solution for uncountable loop dillema

Tags: java, css, list, while-loop, css-selectors

Supposed I have this kind of loop in java (not an exact code, neither it's a truly valid code, but just to give you a general perspective of situation):

```
print "<ul>";
while (res = fetch(database)) {
    print ("<li>" + res.col['data'] + "</li>");
}
print "</ul>";
```

and I have this CSS, which makes the last item on the list has red color.

```
ul li:last-child { color: red; }
```

this works fine on most browsers. the problems are:

- I need to make this work on IE8 too.
- IE8 doesn't support last-child.
- I cannot test whether current iteration of "while" is entering last iteration or not. or let's say, there's no way I could check when the loop would end. this is not an ordinary loop, but let's just say like that. so I can't give the last `<li>` a class, say `class="lastchild"`.
- I also tried with javascript and jquery, and both can't select "last-child" either, as they depends on the css for the selection, I think.

how is the best approach in this situation? thanks.

Comment: I were looking at that question before I post this question. but that question differs from mine in that it only has two column. which is easy solution, by adding a class. I read that on one of that question's solution. my problem is an uncountable loop, which is really uncountable. with no way to test and detect when the loop will end.

Comment: http://selectivizr.com/ never tested, but you should look into that: js emulation for pseudo selectors in explorer

Comment: @LorenzoBoccaccia looks like a viable solution. I'll try to look into it. :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print "<ul>";
String liText=null;
while (res = fetch(database)) {
    if (liText!=null) {
        print ("<li>" + liText + "</li>");
    }
    liText=res.col['data'];
}

if (liText!=null) {
    print ("<li style='the last element style'>" + liText + "</li>");
}
print "</ul>";
```

Move the adding of the last line out of the while and apply desired style there

Comment: I think this can works. I'll try it first. why I never thought of it this way... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the problem is in Java, I am wondering why there is no way to detect last record. Probably you need to reconsider you data structure first, populate the data in a Map or a List and then iterate over.

And, if that is not possible, you can possibly opt for a StringBuilder instnace to build the entire String html tags first by looping over and then replace the last li element with the desired style and after that put it in the print statement for rendering.

The above points are valid even if you are trying to code in javascript, with little bit of change.

Comment: because it's actually Enfinity, which is a framework on top of Java. to fetch the database and to print it goes to custom tags, which is making things complicated, as I can't examine the data on the loop. even fetching data from the loop and the loop itself has to be done using custom tags. The only things that in my realm of manipulation is the <ul>, </ul>, <li> and </li>, as that's what I actually print on my codes. the other things are printed by whatever code goes in the custom tags, which is developed by other people(s).

Comment: Okay...sorry..did't thought of that. Thanks, anyways. I think StanislavL's solution should help. If not, try jquery element selector based on Id, but that would be little complex as compared to the StanislavL's solution.

Comment: it's okay haha. ya, stanislav's solution works. I just only need a logical solution. :) thanks for your respond.